# If $f$ is ergodic and $N \subset X$ is nowhere dense with positive measure then averages do not converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems

Suppose $f: X \to X$ is ergodic on a borel probability measure and $N \subset X$ is nowhere dense with positive measure.  We want to show that the time averages $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}I_N(f^i(x))$ cannot converge uniformly.

My attempt:  We have for a.e. $x$ the time averages converge to the measure of $N$ so we are done if we can find at least one point $x_k$ whose orbit misses $N$ from $1$ to $k$.  This is equivalent to saying that dense set $U=X-\bar{N}$ satisfies $\bigcap_{i=0}^{k-1}f^{-i}(U) \neq \emptyset$.  This seems easy since the ergodicity of $f$ implies at least one transitive orbit in the support but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Any assumptions on the topology of $X$? Is it a metric space?

Comment: No, $f$ wasn't assumed to be continuous either

Comment: I believe it needs to have some assumption. The identity map on the real line with the Dirac measure supported on the origin is ergodic, the set $N = \{0\}$ is nowhere dense and the time averages converges uniformly (at least on the full measure set $N$).

Comment: Would it help if I added that it's a borel measure?  The author assumed everything has that property anyways

Comment: The example I gave uses a Borel measure. I think I was misunderstanding it, maybe asking $N$ to be nowhere dense in its support instead of considering the whole space would solve it, at least my counterexample wouldn't work anymore

Comment: @AmadeusMaldonado This is not a counterexample though, as uniform convergence here is taken over the whole topological space, not just $N$.

Comment: It's asking for uniform convergence everywhere I believe

Comment: But the sequence doesn't even need to converge everywhere, we know it converges on a full measure set

Comment: I'm trying to find such a sequence

Comment: Consider the irrational rotation on the circle that is famously ergodic with the usual measure. Take $A$ the complement of the orbit of a point $p$, then notice that $p$ never enters $A$ by definition, but for almost every point the time averages converge to the measure of the set, that is $1$. You can even change a bit the example of $A$ to make it so that the time average on $p$ never converges, not even to $0$.

Comment: @AmadeusMaldonado $A$ is definitely not nowhere dense here though. The complement of any countable set is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @K.Power What I'm saying is that, in general, the time average doesn't converge in the entire space, the set of points that it converges only has total measure. This means that we need to show uniform convergence but only looking at the set of points such that the time average converges

Comment: @AmadeusMaldonado Well yes that is well known that the convergence is only a.e. in general. There are however cases where the convergence is uniform everywhere, for example uniquely ergodic measures with continuous functions. You still have to find a counterexample to the OP's question, Or prove it. The question is asking whether in such a situation there is NO possibility of uniform convergence of the time average. You can't change the question to be about uniform convergence only on some strict subset.

Comment: @K.Power But then you can pick any example (like an irrational rotation and pick some nowhere dense set $N$) and now consider the space $X$ as a disjoint union of a circle with this irrational rotation and some other circle with the identity, but now pick the measure to be supported on the first circle.

Comment: @AmadeusMaldonado I don't see how that solves the problem? All you've done is given an example of a space non-uniform convergence, which we already have many of? The questions asks to prove it is true for all spaces?

Comment: @K.Power sorry, I got things mixed up. But then isn’t my first identity example a counterexample? The time average sequence is constant since it’s the identity map, so it converges uniformly on the entire space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128956/discussion-between-amadeus-maldonado-and-k-power).

Comment: You certainly want to assume something about $f$ (continuity?). Otherwise you have a counterexample when $N$ is an arc on a circle and you can conjugate it by a Borel measurable measure-preserving bijection so that the image of the arc becomes nowhere dense.

Comment: Assuming $X$ is compact metric and $f$ is continuous, the preimages of $N$ under $f$ are nowhere dense, so their union is meager by the Baire theorem. Thus there is a comeager measurable set $M$ such that the orbit of any point in $M$ avoids $N$. Since $N$ has positive measure time averages of $I_N$ can not converge uniformly to a continuous function.